# get specific substring from command window output (time from ping)

Tags: java, regex, ping

Hi i'm getting ping information from command windows execution. I want to read that information into my Java code.  I only want to retain and use the time information.

This is my sample output from the ping command (input to Java code):

```
    Esecuzione di Ping 10.10.0.161 con 32 byte di dati:
Risposta da 10.10.0.161: byte=32 durata=3ms TTL=64

Statistiche Ping per 10.10.0.161:
    Pacchetti: Trasmessi = 1, Ricevuti = 1, 
    Persi = 0 (0% persi),
Tempo approssimativo percorsi andata/ritorno in millisecondi:
    Minimo = 3ms, Massimo =  3ms, Medio =  3ms
```

But i would like to extract only this:

```
durata=3ms
```

this is the code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?durata=(.*?ms) ",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);               
                Matcher m = null;
                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        m = pattern.matcher(inputLine);

                        if (m.find()) {
                            packet.setSendTime(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));

                                    piii= m.group(1);
                                    System.out.println(piii);
                        }
                }
```

**EDIT**

This is my actual code, end the macther doesn't find nothing.

```
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine())!= null){
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            pingResult += "\n"+inputLine;
        }

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("durata=(\\d+)ms");
        Matcher m = null;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
               m = pattern.matcher(inputLine);

               if (m.find()) {
                     packet.setSendTime(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));
                     piii= m.group(1);
                     System.out.println("Time: " +piii);
                }
        }

        in.close();
```

My output doesn't show me the information I want at `System.out.println(piii);`

Why doesn't by code extract the duration time?  Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to include your initialisation of the variable `in`, but we can assume it is an `BufferedReader`, right?  I guess you've checked with a `System.out.println` that the lines you're getting in `inputLIne` are what you expect and the problem is with the Regular expression.  Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: yes sorry, 'in' is 'BufferReader'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit following OP edits***

The problem is the way you are using your input stream.  You iterate through it to print out the ping command output with this code:

```
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine())!= null){
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        pingResult += "\n"+inputLine;
    }
```

but you then try to do the processing using this code:

```
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
           m = pattern.matcher(inputLine);
```

unfortunately, the ping command has already completed, you have processed all its results (outputting and appending them to `pingResult`) and your input stream is empty, so you'll never get into this second loop.

You have a few options:

1. simply delete the first while loop.  This would mean that you didn't see the output of the `ping` command on your terminal in real time.
2. If that's a problem - move the following line into the second while loop and then delete the first loop.

   ```
       System.out.println(inputLine);
   ```
3. Another option, if you really want to keep the first loop, is to use the `pingResult` String you collect in the first loop as the input for the second.

I've left the sections below to answer other aspects of the question, resolved by OP edits.

---

***Complete explanation of all aspects***

As your code stands, I would expect it to throw an Exception when you try

```
packet.setSendTime(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)))
```

This is because m.group(1) will return the first group within your match - which will be (in your example) `3ms`.  As `3ms` is not purely numeric, I would expect `parseInt` to throw a `NumberFormatException`.  I've tried to replicate your problem by putting ping output into a String and initialising `in` to a `BufferedReader` reading that string.  I get a `NumberFormatException`

To fix that, change your `Pattern` regular expression.  The brackets around terms define groups (see [the description of how this works in the API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg)).  So use

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?durata=(.*?)ms ",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE |
                Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Note the tiny change in the position of the close bracket.  With that - your code should work.

***EDIT***

Added the code that worked for me:

```
public class PingReader
{

    static final String pingOut = "    Esecuzione di Ping 10.10.0.161 con 32 byte"
            + " di dati:\n"
            + "Risposta da 10.10.0.161: byte=32 durata=3ms TTL=64\n\n"
            + "Statistiche Ping per 10.10.0.161:\n"
            + "    Pacchetti: Trasmessi = 1, Ricevuti = 1,\n"
            + "    Persi = 0 (0% persi),\n"
            + "Tempo approssimativo percorsi andata/ritorno in millisecondi:\n"
            + "    Minimo = 3ms, Massimo =  3ms, Medio =  3ms";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
    {
        StringReader inReader = new StringReader(pingOut);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inReader);
        String inputLine = "";      

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?durata=(.*?)ms ",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE |
                Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);               
        Matcher m = null;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                m = pattern.matcher(inputLine);

                if (m.find()) {
                    int sendTime = (Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)));

                           String piii= m.group(1);
                            System.out.println(piii);
                }
        }       
    }
}
```

***EDIT 2***

As always with Regular expressions, there are many ways to get what you want.

You can substitute the following for your pattern, might be easier to follow what is going on:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("durata=(\\d+)ms");
```

In this case, the string required is in a known case (ping will always output lower case) so `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITVE` is not required, we're not matching end of lines, so `Pattern.MULTLINE` is not required and, with my new pattern, we only match the bit we're interested in so `Pattern.DOTALL` is not required.

Note that d matches only digits and the + sign means we want one of more.

This still works with my example.

Comment: i did the change that you say, the position of the brackets, but when i try to print the number from "durata", i didnt see anything. Im trying to get only the 3 from durata=3ms

Comment: i added a string in the last println to see if the m.find() return true..but it never reaches that line..the find() return always false, i think that the matcher never find my pattern

Comment: `Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            `

Comment: this is my buffer reader...sorry for too may comments..i dont know how to use well this site

Comment: I added my actual code how Edit of the answer